# Carrierwave Mongoid Image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, carrierwave, gridfs

Need a little guidance please. 
I set this up pretty much default with `AvatarUploader` via [carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave-mongoid](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave-mongoid) and the files save fine via Gridfs

The problem is when I use an `image_tag` I get the url that looks like `http://some.domain.com/images/uploaded/users/avatar/:user_id/:file_name`

I need the image to be viewable publicly 
The docs do not really tell you what to do.

I cannot access this file via HTTP for the `image_tag`. I get `No route matches [GET] "/images/uploads/user/avatar/...` 
Any ideas? I am new with carrierwave.

**Rails 5.0.2**,
**carrierwave (0.11.2)**,
**carrierwave-mongoid (0.10.0)**,
**mongoid (6.0.2)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After no help and more research I found what to do.
Using my image_url `http://some.domain.com/images/uploaded/users/avatar/:user_id/:file_name`

You first need to create a `GridfsController` then create the methods for sending the data:

```
def avatar
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    content = @user.avatar.read
    if stale?(etag: content, public: true)
        send_data content, type: @user.avatar.file.content_type, disposition: "inline"
        expires_in 0, public: true
    end
end

def thumb_avatar
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    content = @user.avatar.tiny_thumb.read
    if stale?(etag: content, public: true)
        send_data content, type: @user.avatar.tiny_thumb.file.content_type, disposition: "inline"
        expires_in 0, public: true
    end
end
```

Then configure the `grid_fs_access_url` in `initializers/carrierwave.rb` (You will probably have to create the file)

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.grid_fs_access_url = "/images"
end
```

Then you have to create the routes

```
match '/images/uploads/user/avatar/:id/:filename' => 'gridfs#avatar', via: :get
match '/images/uploads/user/avatar/:id/:filename' => 'gridfs#thumb_avatar', constraints: { filename: /thumb.*/ }, via: :get
```

Now you can access the image using the `image_tag`. You can figure more routes and `GridfsController` methods to fit your needs.

Comment: what if using storage file? instead of gridfs? thanks